# Plot a line on the closed price of the first bar that meets condition

Tags: pine-script

UPDATE: Adding complete script.

Objective: Create a line (similar to hline) on close price of the most **recent** distribution day. I need the line to extend from 50 bars before this bar till last bar (today).

I am stuck in the `for loop` and usage of `var`and unable to retrieve the correct values.

```
 //@version=4
study(title="Distribution", shorttitle="Distribution Study", format=format.volume, overlay=true, resolution="1D")

//Input Parameters
distributionDayThreshold    = -0.4

//-----------------------------------------------

//Functions -------------------------------------
hasVolumeIncreased      = (volume-volume[1]) > 0
priceChangePercent      = (close-close[1])/close[1]*100

//Get All Distribution Days
getDistributionDays     = ((priceChangePercent < distributionDayThreshold ) and (hasVolumeIncreased))

conditionBool = getDistributionDays
var bar = -1
var barClose = -1.0
var barFlag = false
var index = -1

for i=0 to bar_index
    if conditionBool[i] and not barFlag
        bar             := bar_index[i]
        barClose        := close[i]
        barFlag         := true
        index           := i
        
plot(barClose, title="barClose")

//Paint all distribution days
bgcolor(conditionBool?color.red : na, title="distributionDay")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must declare your variable with the `var` keyword.
That way, it'll keep it's value throughout the script.

See [Variable declaration](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/language/Expressions_declarations_and_statements.html#variable-declaration) in the user manual.

Excerpt: *The var keyword is a special modifier that instructs the compiler to create and initialize the variable only once. This behavior is very useful in cases where a variable’s value must persist through the iterations of a script across successive bars.*

Edit 29/01/2021:
This is the solution to your updated question.

```
//@version=4
// Cannot use resolution parameter due to error: [line 8: The 'resolution' argument is incompatible with functions that have side effects.]
study(title="Distribution", shorttitle="Distribution Study", format=format.volume, overlay=true) //, resolution="D") 

//Input Parameters
distributionDayThreshold    = input(-0.4)
drawLineBarsBack            = input(50)

//Variables -------------------------------------
var line    hline                   = line.new(na, na, na, na, extend=extend.right, color=color.purple)
var int     bar_last_distribution   = na
var float   close_last_distribution = na

//Functions -------------------------------------
hasVolumeIncreased      = change(volume) > 0
priceChangePercent      = change(close) / close[1] * 100

//Check if it's a distribution day
isDistributionDay       = (priceChangePercent < distributionDayThreshold) and hasVolumeIncreased

if isDistributionDay
    line.set_xy1(hline, bar_index - (bar_index >= drawLineBarsBack ? drawLineBarsBack : 0), close)
    line.set_xy2(hline, bar_index,                                                          close)

//Paint all distribution days
bgcolor(isDistributionDay ? color.red : na, title="distributionDay")
```

Comment: Thanks. I have updated my post with the results.

Comment: You should post the entire script instead of a snippet. That way the community can assist you better.

Comment: Done. :) Updated the question with complete code and problem statement.

Comment: Exactly what I needed to achieve. Cheers! 
Could you also please point out why my logic was not functioning as intended? What could I change in the for loop / var usage to implement it that way. Not necessarily the best practice but I want to understand what went wrong.

Comment: I think your logic was not functioning as intended, because you've written it like a normal programming language would execute it. That's not the case with Pine. Pine runs your script on every historical bar and on every tick change on a realtime bar. You might want to read [Execution model of Pine scripts](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/Quickstart_guide.html#execution-model-of-pine-scripts) to get a better understanding.

Comment: Learned something very useful today. Many thanks